# Textarea content produces error when trying to be alerted in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I created a HTML form that submits to a PHP script. The script should just write content of a dynamically created `input` element as an argument to `alert` JavaScript function. The input is from WYSIWYG editor (CKEditor).

When I input multiple lines of text in the editor and I press the submit button of the form, Firebug shows that the `woa.php` (form’s target) produces an error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

alert("<p>Hi watsup<p>
```

How can I solve this?

Page with form:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="./ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="woa.php" id="myForm">
<textarea name='editor1'></textarea>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var textContent = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var userInput = document.createElement("input");
        userInput.type = "hidden";
        userInput.name = "userInput";
        userInput.value = textContent.getData();

        var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        myForm.appendChild(userInput);
    }
}
</script>
<button id="button">finish edit</button>
<button>save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Target of the form (`woa.php`):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
alert("<?php echo $_POST['userInput']; ?>");
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by generating valid JS code so you don't get those syntax errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not like line breaks inside strings. You have to change newlines to escape sequences. Use

```
alert("<?php echo strtr($_POST["userInput"], array("\r" => '', "\n" => '\n')); ?>");
```